# Rusty fasteners

Tags: rust

I changed bolts on my Jamis steel framed bike because they were rusty. Within 4 days they rusted again.

The derailleur is not rusty.  This bike is stored in a dry building along with another bike that is not rusty.  After I changed the bolts the second time I stored it on our porch under the roof. They rusted again.

Jerr

Comment: Did you use any lube on the bolts?

Comment: Obviously, those bolts have not been stainless steel bolts. That's common and expected. Usually, the steel used for bolts is a bit slower to rust, though. Or it's coated against rust. Or covered in with a thin layer of grease. Speaking of which: Normal procedure for installing many bolts is to put a speck of grease on the tip, so that the screwing action spreads the grease across the entire thread. That grease stays there and keeps the water out, allowing you to easily unscrew the bolt five years later.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the bolts from? Most local hardware /big box store sell what would be considered low quality hardware. I would suggest either sourcing stainless steel replacement hardware or cleaning and painting your current replacements. Some hardware has unique features in particular stem clamping bolts tend to have a slightly smaller head than standard.